# Jenkins + (yarn or npm) - how to set build number from command line

Tags: jenkins, npm, yarnpkg

I'm pretty 'new' to nodejs world and currently trying to automate regular build of UI application using Jenkins. I'm stuck with the task which seems to be a typical one - how to set the 'build number' part of the version from command line before the actual build.

I'm going to follow https://semver.org/ and have resulting version number like following:

```
1.2.0-dev.235
```

Where

- 1.2.0 - are the versions defined by developers and committed into VCS.
- dev.235 - is the tag autogenerated during build and it says 'dev' as the branch name and '235' is build number generated by Jenkins.

So far I could find standard way to explicitly set 'build number' and not touching the 'major.minor.patch' part.

Ideally it would nice be to have that in one command line like following:

```
yarn build --build-number dev.235
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since no 'officially good' answer was found so far, I've implemented a dirty hack, which works at least for me.

My solution is following...

1) Build script in Jenkins (a step of type "Execute shell"):

```
yarn install
node prebuild.js $MYPRJ_BUILD_NUMBER
yarn build
```

2) `prebuild.js` takes some values from `package.json` and some values from build environment variables (MYPRJ_BUILD_NUMBER) and generates `src/buildNumber.ts` file which initially has following content in Git repo

```
// Warning: this will be re-generated on build server
export const APP_VERSION: string = "0.0.0";
export const APP_BUILD_NUMBER: string = "localDev";
```

Text of `prebuild.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var package = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8'));
var version = package.version
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var buildNumber = args[0] || process.env.MYPRJ_BUILD_NUMBER || 'localDev'
var buildNumberFn = "./src/buildNumber.ts";
var buildNumberTs = 
    "// Warning: this will be re-generated on build server\n" + 
    "export const APP_VERSION: string = \"" + version + "\";\n" + 
    "export const APP_BUILD_NUMBER: string = \"" + buildNumber + "\";\n"

fs.writeFileSync(buildNumberFn, buildNumberTs);
console.info("Generated into " + buildNumberFn + "\n: " + buildNumberTs);
```

3) Generated build number can be imported into any place of application just like any other JS staff:

```
import * as appVersion from './buildNumber';

function showVersion(backendVersion) {
    const version = document.createElement('div');
    version.style.cssText = "position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; font: 9px Arial; color: gray; color: lightgrey; z-index: 1000; padding: 0 7px;";
    version.textContent = "UI: " + appVersion.APP_VERSION + "-" + appVersion.APP_BUILD_NUMBER + ", Srv: " + backendVersion;
    document.body.appendChild(version);
}
```